# Is it possible to make very large diamonds using a pressure vessel at several GigaPascal pressure?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, structural-engineering, materials, stresses, industrial-engineering

Nanocrystalline diamonds can be synthesized by direct conversion of graphite or carbon black mixed with low amount of boron (0.1%-10%) at 8-10 GPa, according to US patent No.20120255236.

If some scientists decided to make very large monolithic diamonds (tens of cm size) to make for example large diamond anvil cells with a centimeter sample size, would it be practical to use large pressure vessels with very thick steel walls to reach such very high hydrostatic pressures for such a large volume?

How to calculate the required material thickness to withstand such high pressures?

Comment: See, how well looks your question after my edit.

Comment: Just takes lots of money and massive containers.  But why bother when there are simpler (chemical) methods?

Comment: Carl Witthoft , what is the simpler method to make 10 cm size diamond ? I didn’t hear about something similar

Answer (score 1):

Such a pressure vessel is not technically achievable with current technology. See [this question](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/2551/gigapascal-pressures-in-a-small-package).

There are two main methods of making synthetic diamonds. HPHT (High pressure, high temperature), which uses something like a [Diamond Anvil Cell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diamond_anvil_cell) to achieve pressures in the Gigapascal range and temperatures over 1400 $^o$C. The largest diamonds produced this way seem to be in the 1-2 cm range but it is difficult to get reliable information on this.

The other main method is CVD (Chemical Vapor Deposition) which doesn't require high pressures. A research team at the Carnegie Institute of Washington has developed a method to produce larger diamonds using CVD. See [article in New Scientist](https://www.newscientist.com/article/dn16036-artificial-diamonds-now-available-in-extra-large/). Apparently diamonds in the inch range are possible using their method. They also believe that larger sizes will be achievable in the future.